# Unknown host error in Team Explorer

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, team-explorer-everywhere

I have a project created at https://myteamprojct-sharvil.visualstudio.com. I want to configure this in Eclipse using Team Explorer Everywhere. I am behind a proxy and have configured the same in Eclipse. I am using Eclipse Mars. When I try to connect to Team Foundation Server, I get an error Unknown Host myteamproject-sharvil.visualstudio.com . Following is the screenshot.

[image]

I tried searching the internet for a solution but couldn't come across one. Can someone please help me to resolve this?

All help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try adding the port too?

Comment: Can you connect via the web?

Comment: Did you configure the proxy for Team Explorer Everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

This same question was asked here (by the same person):
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b21633a1-2f3d-4876-bf10-0e0af419bd6d/unknown-host-error-while-connecting-to-team-services?forum=tee

There are already some responses on that thread.